# Find previous occurrence of a value and get value in opposite column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I have data like this:

```
    stim1 stim2 
 1:     2     3               
 2:     1     3                
 3:     2     1             
 4:     1     2            
 5:     3     1          

structure(list(stim1 = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L),
               stim2 = c(3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L)),
          row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

My objective is to add two columns: one for 'stim1' and one for 'stim2'. For each row of both columns, I want to find the previous occurrence of its value, in either column, and then grab the value in the opposite column.

For example, on row 3 'stim1' is 2. The previous occurrence of 2 is in 'stim1' on row 1. The value in the other column of that row is 3. So `Prev1[3]` is 3.

Another example: On row 4 'stim1' is 1. The previous occurrence of 1 is in 'stim2' on row 3. The value in the other column on that row is 2. So `Prev1[4]` is 2.

Desired output:

```
    stim1 stim2       Prev1  Prev2  
 1:     2     3       <NaN>  <NaN>         
 2:     1     3       <NaN>    2          
 3:     2     1         3      3
 4:     1     2         2      1
 5:     3     1         1      2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick helper function to iterate through the data:

```r
func <- function(mtx) {
  na <- mtx[1][NA]
  c(NA, sapply(seq_len(nrow(mtx))[-1], function(ind) {
    v <- mtx[ind,1] ; s <- seq_len(ind-1)
    m <- cbind(v == mtx[s,1], v == mtx[s,2])
    if (any(m)) {
      m <- which(m, arr.ind = TRUE)
      row <- which.max(m[,1])
      mtx[m[row,1], m[row,2] %% 2 + 1]
    } else na
  }))
}
```

Demonstration:

```r
dat[, Prev1 := func(cbind(stim1, stim2)) ][, Prev2 := func(cbind(stim2, stim1)) ]
#    stim1 stim2 Prev1 Prev2
#    <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:     2     3    NA    NA
# 2:     1     3    NA     2
# 3:     2     1     3     3
# 4:     1     2     2     1
# 5:     3     1     1     2
```

---

Alternative, using `zoo::rollapply`:

```r
func2 <- function(mtx) {
  na <- mtx[1][NA]
  if (!is.matrix(mtx)) return(na) # we're on the first row
  v <- mtx[nrow(mtx),1] ; s <- seq_len(nrow(mtx)-1)
  m <- cbind(v == mtx[s,1], v == mtx[s,2])
  if (any(m)) {
    m <- which(m, arr.ind = TRUE)
    row <- which.max(m[,1])
    mtx[m[row,1], m[row,2] %% 2 + 1]
  } else na
}
dat[, Prev1 := zoo::rollapplyr(.SD, .N, FUN = func2, by.column = FALSE, partial = TRUE),
    .SDcols = c("stim1", "stim2")
    ][, Prev2 := zoo::rollapplyr(.SD, .N, FUN = func2, by.column = FALSE, partial = TRUE),
      .SDcols = c("stim2", "stim1") ]
```

It's not shorter, and in fact is *slower* (with a 5-row dataset), but if you prefer to think of this in a rolling fashion, this produces the same results. (It's possible the newer `slider` package might be clearer, faster, or neither compared with this.)

---

Note:

- I assign `na` as a class-specific `NA` (there are at least six types of `NA`). I do this defensively: if there is at least one match, then the remainder of the `NA` values will be coerced into the correct class; however, if there are no matches, then the class returned by `func` will be `logical` which may not be the same as the original data, and `data.table` will complain.

Answer (score 3):

The tricky thing is that the OP wants to find the previous occurrence of a value *in either column*.

Therefore, the idea is to reshape the data into long format and to find the matching rows by *aggregating in a non-equi self join*.

```
library(data.table)
long <- melt(DT, measure.vars = patterns("^stim"), value.name = "stim")[
  , rn := rowid(variable)][
    , opposite := rev(stim), keyby = rn][]
long[, prev := long[long, on = c("stim", "rn < rn"), 
                    .(max(x.rn), x.opposite[which.max(x.rn)]), by = .EACHI]$V2][] 
dcast(long, rn ~ rowid(rn), value.var = c("stim", "prev"))
```

> ```
>    rn stim_1 stim_2 prev_1 prev_2
> 1:  1      2      3     NA     NA
> 2:  2      1      3     NA      2
> 3:  3      2      1      3      3
> 4:  4      1      2      2      1
> 5:  5      3      1      1      2
> ```

#### Explanation

1. Reshape `DT` to long format.
2. Create an additional column `rn` which identifies the row numbers in the original dataset `DT` using `rowid(variable)`.
3. Create an additional column `opposite` which contains the values of the opposite column. In long format this means to reverse the order of values *within each `rn` group*.
4. Now, join `long` with itself. The non-equi join condition is looking for all occurrences of the current `stim` value in rows *before the current row*. As there might be more than one match, aggregating by `max(rn)` within the `.EACHI` groups picks the row number *of the previous occurrence of the value* as well as the corresponding `opposite` value. So,
   `long[long, on = c("stim", "rn < rn"), .(max(x.rn), x.opposite[which.max(x.rn)]), by = .EACHI]`
   returns

   > ```
   >     stim rn V1 V2
   >  1:    2  1 NA NA
   >  2:    3  1 NA NA
   >  3:    1  2 NA NA
   >  4:    3  2  1  2
   >  5:    2  3  1  3
   >  6:    1  3  2  3
   >  7:    1  4  3  2
   >  8:    2  4  3  1
   >  9:    3  5  2  1
   > 10:    1  5  4  2
   > ```
5. Create an additional column `prev` in `long` which contains the *previous opposite* value `V2`.
6. Finally, reshape `long` back to wide format, using both measure columns `stim` and `prev`.

#### Edit: Alternative solution

In case `DT` contains more columns that just `stim1` and `stim2`, `DT` can be updated by reference, alternatively:

```
long <- melt(DT, measure.vars = patterns("^stim"), value.name = "stim")[
  , rn := rowid(variable)][
    , opposite := rev(stim), keyby = rn][]
DT[, c("prev1", "prev2") := dcast(
  long[long, on = c("stim", "rn < rn"), 
       .(max(x.rn), x.opposite[which.max(x.rn)]), by = .EACHI], 
  rn ~ rowid(rn), value.var = "V2")[, rn := NULL]][]
```

> ```
>    stim1 stim2 prev1 prev2
> 1:     2     3    NA    NA
> 2:     1     3    NA     2
> 3:     2     1     3     3
> 4:     1     2     2     1
> 5:     3     1     1     2
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(stim1 = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L),
                 stim2 = c(3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case there was interest in a `tidyverse` approach (probably not as fast!). You could add row numbers to your data.frame, and put it into long form. Then, grouping by each value, get the previous row number and `stim` to reference in `Prev`. With a `left_join` you can obtain the appropriate value for `Prev`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- mutate(as.data.frame(df), rn = row_number())

df_long <- pivot_longer(df, 
                        cols = -rn, 
                        names_to = "stim", 
                        names_pattern = "stim(\\d+)", 
                        names_transform = list(stim = as.numeric))

df_long %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  mutate(match_rn = lag(rn), match_stim = 3 - lag(stim)) %>%
  left_join(df_long, by = c("match_rn" = "rn", "match_stim" = "stim")) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = rn, 
              names_from = stim, 
              values_from = value.y, 
              names_prefix = "Prev") %>%
  right_join(df) %>%
  arrange(rn)
```

**Output**

```
     rn Prev1 Prev2 stim1 stim2
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1    NA    NA     2     3
2     2    NA     2     1     3
3     3     3     3     2     1
4     4     2     1     1     2
5     5     1     2     3     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option:

```
setDT(DT)[, rn := .I]

dt1 <- DT[DT, on=.(stim1, rn<rn), mult="last", .(x.rn, v=x.stim2)]
dt2 <- DT[DT, on=.(stim2=stim1, rn<rn), mult="last", .(x.rn, v=x.stim1)]
DT[, Prev1 := fcoalesce(fifelse(dt1$x.rn > dt2$x.rn, dt1$v, dt2$v), dt1$v, dt2$v)]

#have not flipped everything and seems to work for this minimal example, pls let me know if there are cases where Prev2 is wrong
dt1 <- DT[DT, on=.(stim2, rn<rn), mult="last", .(x.rn, v=x.stim1)]
dt2 <- DT[DT, on=.(stim1=stim2, rn<rn), mult="last", .(x.rn, v=x.stim2)]
DT[, Prev2 := fcoalesce(fifelse(dt1$x.rn > dt2$x.rn, dt1$v, dt2$v), dt1$v, dt2$v)]
```

output:

```
   stim1 stim2 rn Prev1 Prev2
1:     2     3  1    NA    NA
2:     1     3  2    NA     2
3:     2     1  3     3     3
4:     1     2  4     2     1
5:     3     1  5     1     2
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- structure(list(stim1 = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L),
               stim2 = c(3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L)),
          row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```